# Customize more button of tabbar

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I am stuck in a situation where I want to change the text of default more button of tabbar, In my case we need 7 tabs and iOS moves the additional tabs under more, I want to change the text of that tab.

can anyone help on the same?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can change the title and the icon like this:

**Swift:**

```html
tabBarController?.moreNavigationController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Title", image: UIImage(named: "image"), tag: 0)
```

**Objective-C**

```html
tabBarController.moreNavigationController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"] tag:0];
```